# How to fix activemq error which is appear after oo-install script is finished successfully?

Tags: activemq-classic, openshift

I just tried to install openshift by oo-install to CentOS 6.5 (clear minimal OS), installation process finished successfully but it's look like the 'broker' is not running. I tried to understand that part is broken and found that
ActiveMQ is not started at boot and it has this error in /var/log/activemq/activemq.log

```
2014-06-22 16:45:28,085 [erSimpleAppMain] INFO  XBeanBrokerFactory$1           - Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.    XBeanBrokerFactory$1@38d9e447: startup date [Sun Jun 22 16:45:28 YEKT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-06-22 16:45:34,239 [erSimpleAppMain] ERROR XBeanBrokerFactory             - Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml],     reason: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.    xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'activemq.data' in string value "${activemq.data}"
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.    XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'activemq.data' in string value     "${activemq.data}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.    java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.    java:662)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:125)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:84)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Also in /var/log/activemq/wrapper.log exist another error message:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/22 16:45:08 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/22 16:45:08 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 64-bit 3.5.9
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/22 16:45:08 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2011 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/22 16:45:08 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/22 16:45:08 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/22 16:45:08 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:19 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 | Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_55 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/    jre
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 |   Heap sizes: current=44608k  free=40256k  max=506816k
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 |     JVM args: -Dactivemq.home=/usr/share/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/usr/share/activemq -Dcom.    sun.management.jmxremote -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Xmx512m -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib:/usr/lib64 -Dwrapper.    key=8FoxAdsYaZZj3A_f -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.    disable_console_input=TRUE -Dwrapper.pid=993 -Dwrapper.version=3.5.9 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper    .cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 | Extensions classpath:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 |   [/usr/share/activemq/lib,/usr/share/activemq/lib/camel,/usr/share/activemq/lib/optional,/    usr/share/activemq/lib/web,/usr/share/activemq/lib/extra]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 | ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /usr/share/activemq
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 | ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /usr/share/activemq
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 | ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /usr/share/activemq/conf
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:21 | ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /usr/share/activemq/data
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:25 | Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 | ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework    .beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0'     defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'activemq.data' in string value "${activemq.data}"
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 | java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.    factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in     class path resource [activemq.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'activemq.data' in string value "${activemq.data}"
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:108)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:290)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean     definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Could not     resolve placeholder 'activemq.data' in string value "${activemq.data}"
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.    doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.    processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.    postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.    invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.    invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:662)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(    AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(    ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(    ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:101)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(    XBeanBrokerFactory.java:101)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:65)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:125)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   ... 16 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 | ERROR: java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:     Invalid bean definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]:     Could not resolve placeholder 'activemq.data' in string value "${activemq.data}"
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 | java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:     Invalid bean definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]:     Could not resolve placeholder 'activemq.data' in string value "${activemq.data}"
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:109)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:290)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean     definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Could not     resolve placeholder 'activemq.data' in string value "${activemq.data}"
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.    doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.    processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.    postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.    invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.    invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:662)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(    AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(    ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(    ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:101)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(    XBeanBrokerFactory.java:101)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:65)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:125)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:84)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/06/22 16:45:34 |   ... 16 more
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/06/22 16:45:36 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I'm completely new to ActiveMq and don't have any idea of this errors nature, therefore I would like to know any way to understand or fix this issue.

PS.
Why oo-install tool is never work correctly? I tried to install openshift few months ago by it to different OS like fedora19, few versions of CentOS 6x and always after installation has finished openshift is didn't started after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer here https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshift-archives/dev/2014-January/msg00056.html

> I think the root problem is that I directed you to the PuppetLabs
>   repos to install Puppet. That was a mistake on my part. Puppet is
>   available through EPEL and that would have been the correct way to
>   install it. Instead, because your Broker had the puppetlabs-deps repo
>   on it, the wrong Puppet package was installed.
>
> To correct this:
>   * `yum erase activemq`
>   * Disable the puppetlabs-deps repo (easiest way, change 'enabled=1' to 'enabled=0' in the puppetlabs-deps.repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/)
>   * Rerun `yum install activemq`

this solved my issue, activemq started without errors. But anyway broker is not works yet.